# C++ #include of file makes std types unknown

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a large project library and a few files I added myself. One of them is a header file that contains some `enum`s I use across the project. It looks something like this:

```
#ifndef MYMANYENUMS
#define MYMANYENUMS

namespace my_ns {

enum class RecType { NONE, L1, L2 };
inline int operator+ ( RecType t )
    { return underlying_type<RecType >::type(t); }

static const map<RecType, string> RecTypeMap = {
    { RecType ::NONE, "NONE" },
    { RecType ::L1, "L1" },
    { RecType ::L2, "L2" },
};
}
```

I include this header in a lot of other headers across the project without issues. Now I added a new header file:

```
#ifndef THEOTHERHEADER_H
#define THEOTHERHEADER_H

#include "MyManyEnums.h"

#endif
```

This file is completely empty besides what shown above. As soon as I compile I get errors:

```
map does not name a type
underlying_type was not declared in this scope
```

in my enums header file. I am pretty confused why this all of a sudden breaks. I am using qtcreator and gcc.
I cant create a small example and post here that would replicate the error. I assume it must be an issue with the project structure. But I have no idea where to look and what to try so if someone can point me to potential issues that I can investigate, that would be helpful.

Comment: Well, since you don't include standard headers into your "enums" header, you apparently rely on other files pre-including them for you. If your "other" header is somehow included above that point - you will get these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the other files where you `#include MyManyEnums.h` are including other headers beforehand that happen to define (either directly, or indirectly through other includes) those types.

I am an advocate of header files including any necessary dependencies themselves (in this case, MyManyEnums.h would `#include <type_traits>` and `#include <map>`). The other option is for any consumer of the header to include its prerequisites. Pick a paradigm and stick to it.

Edit:
And as pointed out by Ken Y-N, you need to either specify the `std::` namespace (preferred) or add (limited) `using` declarations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `type_traits` - I missed that one!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is twofold; first, your header file does not `#include <map>` to define the `std::map` class, and second, you use just `map`, not `std::map`, which [you should **NOT** do in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1270789) for precisely this reason.

Perhaps in your C++ file you have something like:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
#include "mymanyenums.h" // Or whatever it is called.
```

But another file uses just:

```
#include "theotherheader.h"
```

Without having the previous three lines to set things up.

So, to conclude, use this:

```
#ifndef MYMANYENUMS
#define MYMANYENUMS

#include <type_traits>
#include <map>

namespace my_ns {

enum class RecType { NONE, L1, L2 };
inline int operator+ ( RecType t )
    { return std::underlying_type<RecType >::type(t); }

static const std::map<RecType, string> RecTypeMap = {
    { RecType ::NONE, "NONE" },
    { RecType ::L1, "L1" },
    { RecType ::L2, "L2" },
};
}

#endif
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. Been a bit blind here. thanks